# How prevent that Bind DNS updates remove $INCLUDE directive

Tags: include, dns, bind

I have a dns server up and running with a zone configured for my domain with the allow-update directive enabled.
I have the initial configuration for the domain in the file /var/cache/bind/db.mydomain.com this file has a line with "$INCLUDE db.aux.mydomain.com" directive to load records from this file.
The problem comes when I do an update of the zone using nsupdate because bind rewrites the file db.mydomain.com by deleting the $INCLUDE line and putting the content of db.aux.mydomain.com directly in db.mydomain.com file.
How I can prevent this?

Comment: This should be on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: This should indeed be on ServerFault, as this is a BIND-related question. That said, it'd be worthwhile to read the man page for nsupdate.